# Oracle stored procedure recompilation and Sprig SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

please help to overcome the following problem.
When I call stored procedure which was recently recompiled I'm getting an error ORA - "ORA-04068: Existing state of packages has been discarded." I know that when connection is closed in code it is just returned to the pool but still exists in the session. I know that that one of the possible solution is to catch this error and call procedure again in catch block, somehow like this:

```
    callProcedure(Params params){

         SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = getSimpleJdbcCall();
            Map<String, Object> results = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
            try {
                results = jdbcCall.execute(params);
            }catch (UncategorizedSQLException ex){
                if (checkOra04067Exception(ex)){
                    callProcedure(params);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        private boolean checkOra04067Exception(UncategorizedSQLException ex){
            return "72000".equals(ex.getSQLException().getSQLState()) && 
                                 ex.getSQLException().getErrorCode() == 4068;
        }
```

But is there more elegant way to overcome this problem, not really wanting to place this try-catch block in many DAO objects where the jdbcCall.execute(params) is used. Yes I can do a wrapper for SimpleJdbcCall with try-catch and inject this wrapper where it is needed but maybe there is a possibility to fine tune datasourse to really close connections or remove them completely once it is returned to connection pool? Or is there a the solution to create any query which can validate an oracle package state and use it in 
"spring.datasource.validation-query" instead of  "select 1 from dual".
Thanks for your help in advance.
P.S I'm using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource and oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

By The way, code has an issue, so the method returns empty result.
It is somehow connected to try-catch block.
The first time when there is an error, the callProcedure(params) method triggers 
once again in catch block and returns result, but then I don't know why but result returns from the call which had been before catch block. And it is an empty map.

Here is my workable solution.
1) Extend  SimpleJdbcCall
2) override execute method:

```
public class MyJdbcCall extends SimpleJdbcCall {

    public MyyJdbcCall(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> execute(SqlParameterSource parameterSource) {
        Map<String, Object> results = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
        try {
            results = executeInternal(parameterSource);
        } catch (UncategorizedSQLException ex) {
            if (checkOra04067Exception(ex)) {
                results = executeInternal(parameterSource);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> executeInternal(SqlParameterSource parameterSource) {
        return super.execute(parameterSource);
    }

    private boolean checkOra04067Exception(UncategorizedSQLException ex) {
        return SQL_STATE_72000.equals(ex.getSQLException().getSQLState())
                && ex.getSQLException().getErrorCode() == SQL_ERROR_CODE_4068;
    }
}
```